# UICollectionView clipping on rotation, fixed as soon as you scroll

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uicollectionview, screen-rotation

I’m using a `UICollectionView` to display three cells vertically, which each contain a `UIView`. It looks something like this:

[image]

If I rotate the device, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I’m using AutoLayout to rotate the collection view, everything seems to be working properly, but when I rotate (this can be from portrait to landscape, or landscape to portrait), the collection view seems to clip its cells. If I turn on the view debugger at this point, it renders it perfectly there, like this:

[image]

As soon as I touch the collection view (i.e. scroll it slightly), the issue is fixed, and from then on it renders properly until I rotate again.

The issue occurs on both simulator and device, and when changing from any orientation to any other. It only clips until the collection view is touched, at which point it fixes itself.

I’ve tried lots of things already, replacing the YouTube views here with regular UIViews, manually calling `scrollViewDidScroll:` on the collection view after I rotate (and before), telling the collection view to reload its data, reload items, turning off clip or mask to bounds, invalidating the auto-resizing constraints, just about everything obvious that I can think of.

What’s puzzling me the most is the view debugger – everything there is perfect, it’s just when it renders out on-screen that it’s clipping. This issue occurs across the board, on all devices, phone and pad. There’s nothing in the view debugger hierarchy that looks like it’s overlapping them. Everything’s where it’s supposed to be, even if I break at the broken point and print frames, etc., it’s just clipping when it renders somehow.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you've got in your cells there, but you might consider making the background color of the collection view and cell visible (preferably different colors like green/red) so you can determine if it's the view in your cell or the collectionView/cell itself.

Comment: Also, what method are you overriding for rotation?  Have you tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the YouTube view?

Comment: Yup, tried that, it's the entire collectionView that's being clipped. But if I print its frame, it's exactly where it should be. The cells contain `YTPlayerView`, which is an embedded YouTube `UIWebView`.

Comment: I'm not overriding anything at present, I'm letting auto-layout handle it. But I've tried overriding everything I can think of, will/didRotate, viewWillTransitionToSize, etc., and calling setNeedsDisplay, layoutImmediately, etc. No joy so far.

Comment: Is there anything in your view hierarchy aside from the collection view?

Comment: Nope, it's the entire view.

Comment: If you can throw the project up somewhere I can poke at it.  Nothing obvious is coming to mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93312/discussion-between-charles-a-and-lukech).